# Error PG::ConnectionBad: local user with ID 1001 does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins, amazon-ec2, psql

I am running a small Rails project on Jenkins using two AWS EC2 instances:

1. One master with Java & Jenkins installed
2. One slave with Java & Git & Docker & PostgreSQL installed

The idea is to put the build of the project into the slave. This is the code:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'ruby:2.6.6'
            label 'linux_slave'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Fetching Git') {
            
            steps {
                git credentialsId: 'user-key',
                    url: 'git@github.com:user/jenkins_project.git'
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'gem install bundler:2.0.1'
                sh 'bundle install'
                sh 'RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rspec --format RspecJunitFormatter --out result_spec.xml'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The git fetch goes right, the bundle goes right and then, when it comes to:

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate
```

The rake is aborted and this message error pops up:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: local user with ID 1001 does not exist
```

I have been trying to search what is this error about and how to fix it but I havent found anything and I am stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like there may be an error with your db connection config in your `database.yml` file. Are you able to run `rails c test` and perform active record methods when you ssh into project root directory?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I dont really know how could I check that. What I have been come to know is that the user of the slave server (user1) has the id of 1001 (the same one as the error). But it does exist if I go into postgres and check the list of users. Also I granted all privileges to the user but nothing changed.  Still the same error. Any ideas...? Thanks!

Comment: I am thinking that maybe it is due to doing all of the procedure inside a docker container due to user the ruby image and that container doesn't have any user?

Comment: After you run into the error, can you ssh into the container and see if you can open up a db prompt using `psql` and the info supplied in your `database.yml` file?

Comment: So the container is removed automatically, the ruby image stays so I just ran a container in the server using the image. When I try to go into the container, i cant run psql since the image only has ruby in it. I installed postgres locally, not on the container. Would it make sense to create an step to always add postgres into the container?

Comment: Okay, so I still don't know why using the docker image doesnt work (my guess is that the user with id 1001 is not in the container with the ruby image thus it gives error). I installed ruby locally, created user1 for psql and it works like a charm. The ideal would be not to have to instal ruby or rake locally though